# Php sum the values in while loop does not work

Tags: php

I have a problem with sum values in while loop.
So, I have a database witch has rows with same product name, but different quantities, different ids and different prices.
When I do my while loop it prints each product, but I want to print only one and sum quantities.

My result is `11123`, not `8`, how it should be.

This is my code:

```
$found = 1;
while($stmt->fetch()){
    if(!($data3['Prod_price'] == '0' || $data3['Prod_name'] == ' Acne Cream')) {
        $price = $data3['Prod_total'] - ($data3['Prod_total'] *($data3['Discount']/100));
        $qty = $data3['Vial_type'] == " 50 Tablete" ? $data3['Prod_qty'] / 2 : $data3['Prod_qty'];
        if($data3['Prod_name'] == ' Antioxidant Star'){
            if($found==1){ // this is for showing only one product with same name 
                $found++;

                // here should be summed quantity divided by target (to extract the percentage)
                $andioxidtrg = $qty / $data2['Trg_antioxidant']; 
                // here shold be the quantity
                $andioxidqty = $qty; 

                echo 'Antioxidant Star: '.$andioxidqty.' din '.$data2['Trg_antioxidant'].' ('.round( $andioxidtrg * 100 )."%)<br>";
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to sum then sum it, you just overwrite the value.

```
$andioxidqty += $qty; // notice the +
```

Edit: this means you also need to add a line above the loop with: `$andioxidqty =0;` or you will get a notice on the first iteration

Comment: How can it be 1 if you say it's `11123`? On the first iteration, yes it's one but when the loop is done you should have 8 as the value in `$andioxidqty`

Comment: if i echo the "$qty" above the "if($found==1){" line the result is "11123" but inside the if statement "if($found==1)" the result is always 1 :(

Comment: `if($found==1){` is true the first iteration, then the very next line makes this if never again be true, `$found++;`. What is this found thing? It does not make any sense

Comment: You are checking found to be equal to 1. then increment it to 1 so result will be incremented only once

Comment: @ZiyaVakhobov I can't accept that edit, it's wrong. PHP typecasts if you add int to a string number. https://3v4l.org/U6Jep

Comment: Note that the previous line to this one also sets `$andioxidtrg`

Comment: the found thing is for showing only one result in while loop: i have Antioxidant Star - 2(this is qty), Antioxidant Star - 3(this is qty) and with found it prints only once (i do not know if this is correct). in fact i want to print the name only once and the quantities to be summed.

Comment: without "$found = 1;" outside while loop and "if($found==1){" inside loop the result printed is Antioxidant Star: 1 din 20 (5%) , Antioxidant Star: 1 din 20 (5%) , Antioxidant Star: 1 din 20 (5%) , Antioxidant Star: 2 din 20 (10%) , Antioxidant Star: 3 din 20 (15%)

Comment: Without the if the code will sum the values **if you have added the + sign as I wrote in answer above**. This question is a rabbit hole, you add stuff to the question and a possible xy problem where you try to solve a problem by asking the wrong question. Add the array to the question and we can help you with a better answer

Comment: You are right Andreas, sorry, my question is in fact how to print the last row in while loop?